# using sql query get all product ids sku and custom attribute (with option fields) value

Tags: magento-1.9

How can i get the following fields using sql query 
**entity_id, sku , Brand**
where brand is custom drop-down attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had created the following query which works for me, may be gave some help to any one:

```
SELECT 
    `e`.`sku` as Sku ,`e`.`entity_id` as Code,`option_value`.`value` as manufacturer
FROM
    `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
     INNER JOIN
    `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `at_manufacturer` ON (`at_manufacturer`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`)
    INNER JOIN
    `eav_attribute_option_value` AS `option_value` on (`at_manufacturer`.`value`=`option_value`.`option_id`)
        AND (`at_manufacturer`.`attribute_id` = '81')
        AND (`at_manufacturer`.`store_id` = 0)
        AND (`option_value`.`store_id` = 0)
WHERE
    (at_manufacturer.value != 'null')
```

you can change 81 with your respective Attr id.